# Warning FXML eclipse

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I would like to ask you why the java compiler gives me the following warning:

> "Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 10.0.1 by JavaFX
>   runtime of version 8.0.151"

and how do I avoid it?

Comment: could you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, the error is warning you are loading an "FXML document with JavaFX API of version 10.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.151". :)

So, if you used Scene Builder to generate the FXML document, you used a version of made for Java 10. But your JDK is for Java 8.

This is generally not a massive issue as the FXML specifications have not changed much between version. But if, in the future, the FXML API is changes, Java 8 would not be aware of the changes and could cause issues.

---

In the meantime, you can avoid the warning by changing your FXML file's root element and removing the following property:

`xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1"` (or however yours is defined).